# Color Changing on click tracker

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors, click

I added a color on the first click and disabled the color on the second click. What I want to be able to do is when the color is already changed I would like to be able to change the color and add that color like as though it is on its first click. For example, I already clicked on a cell and now have a black color. I want to able to change the color from black to red immediately, but also keep my functionality of being to click on something twice to remove the color. Here is my project:

https://codepen.io/frederickalcantara/pen/XVqZep

```
let color = 1;
    cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (color) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.value;
            color = 0;
        } else {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "";
            color = 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So, you want to be able to change a pre-existing black cell to red, right?

Comment: Yes, but on the second click (Without changing the color) I would like to be able to change the value of the background color to an empty string. Which would remove the background color of the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check if the color match the colorPicker value or not

```
if (cell.dataset.color !== colorPicker.value) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.value;
    cell.dataset.color = colorPicker.value;
} else {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "";
    cell.dataset.color = ""
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoLELd?editors=0010

Reason to why I'm setting a dataset color here is because backgroundColor converts the hexadecimal from the colorPicker value to RGB so a check between the two won't work.

Comment: Thank you, that is the solution that I am looking for.